# Enhancing speed / vectorization of for loop including sample-function R

Tags: r, performance, for-loop, vectorization

I am looking for a fast way to create a matrix with integer values that have a certain probability to be chosen. Given a vector `L=c(3,4,2)` and a probability vector `Prob=c(0.4,0.35,0.25,0.1,0.25,0.4,0.25,0.6,0.4)` with `sum(L)` elements, I want to choose, for example, an element between `1:L[1] = 1:3` with probability `Prob[1:L[1]] = c(0.4,0.35,0.25)`. This should be performed over all elements of `L` for several times determined by the parameter `rows` and be stored into a matrix named `POP`.

My solution is very slow because of two for-loops and I am searching a solution with much better performance through vectorization or other techniques.

My solution to this problem looks as follows:

```
L = c(3,4,2)
L_cum = c(0,cumsum(L)) #vector to call vector sections from Prob
Prob = c(0.4,0.35,0.25,0.1,0.25,0.4,0.25,0.6,0.4)  #probability vector for sum(L) elements
rows = 5  #number of rows of matrix POP
POP = matrix(0,rows,length(L)) 

for(i in 1:rows){
 for(j in 1:length(L)){
   POP[i,j] = sample(1:L[j],1,prob=Prob[(L_cum[j]+1):L_cum[j+1]])
 }
}
```

Comment: Have you looked to apply() and similar functions yet?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'd just try:

```
set.seed(1234)
#set the number of extractions
n<-10
vapply(split(Prob,rep(seq_along(L),L)), 
          function(x) sample(length(x),n,replace=TRUE,prob=x),
          integer(n))
#      1 2 3
# [1,] 1 4 1
# [2,] 2 2 1
# [3,] 2 3 1
# [4,] 2 1 1
# [5,] 3 3 1
# [6,] 2 4 2
# [7,] 1 3 1
# [8,] 1 3 2
# [9,] 2 3 2
#[10,] 2 3 1
```

Comment: Thank you, that routine is very quick!